# Creating stored procedure giving error

Tags: plsql

I have created a stored procedure

```
create or replace
   PROCEDURE "USP_USER_ADD" (
       USERNAME                  IN VARCHAR2 ,
       P_PASSWORD                  IN VARCHAR2 ,
       SALT                      IN BLOB ,
       EMAIL                     IN VARCHAR2 ,
       FIRST_NAME                IN VARCHAR2 ,
       LAST_NAME                 IN VARCHAR2 ,
       ip_address                IN VARCHAR2 ,
       EMAIL_VERIFIED            IN NUMBER ,
       ACTIVE                    IN NUMBER ,
       CREATEDBY                 IN VARCHAR2 ,
       CREATED                   IN DATE ,
       MODIFIED                  IN DATE ,
       MODIFIEDBY                IN VARCHAR2 ,
       USER_GROUP_ID             IN NUMBER ,
       LAST_PASSWORD_CHANGE_DATE IN DATE ,
       P_failed_login_attempts     IN NUMBER )
    AS

   BEGIN  

  declare
         user_id_tmp number(20);     

INSERT INTO users( "username" ,
    "password" ,
    "salt" ,
    "email" ,
    "first_name" ,
    "last_name" ,
    "email_verified" ,
    "active" ,
    "ip_address" ,
    "created" ,
    "createdby" ,
    "modified" ,
    "modifiedby" ,
    "user_group_id" ,
    "last_password_change_date" ,
    "FAILED_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS"
  )
  VALUES
  (
    username ,
    p_password ,
    salt ,
    email ,
    first_name ,
    last_name ,
    email_verified ,
    active ,
    ip_address ,
    created ,
    createdby ,
    modified ,
    modifiedby ,
    user_group_id ,
    last_password_change_date ,
    p_failed_login_attempts
  );      

SELECT MAX(id) INTO user_id_tmp FROM users ;

INSERT INTO user_passwords
  (
    "user_id" ,
    "password" ,
    "created"
  )
  VALUES
  (
    user_id_tmp,
    p_password,
    created
  );

  END USP_USER_ADD;
```

It's giving me two errors

> 1: Error(26,5): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "INSERT" when expecting one of the following:     begin function package pragma procedure subtype type use      form    current cursor The symbol "begin" was substituted for "INSERT" to continue.
>
> 2: Error(78,19): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:     begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod    null pragma raise return select update while with          << close current delete fetch lock insert    open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge    pipe

These are my tables

```
          --------------------------------------------------------
          --  DDL for Table USER_PASSWORDS
          --------------------------------------------------------

            CREATE TABLE "NEWS1.0"."USER_PASSWORDS" 
             (  "ID" NUMBER(11,0), 
            "USER_ID" NUMBER(11,0), 
            "PASSWORD" VARCHAR2(255 BYTE), 
            "SALT" VARCHAR2(255 BYTE), 
            "IP" VARCHAR2(15 BYTE), 
            "CREATEDBY" VARCHAR2(255 BYTE), 
            "CREATED" DATE, 
            "MODIFIED" DATE, 
            "MODIFIEDBY" VARCHAR2(255 BYTE)
             ) PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
            STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
            PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)
            TABLESPACE "USERS" ;
          --------------------------------------------------------
          --  DDL for Index USERS_PK
          --------------------------------------------------------

            CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "NEWS1.0"."USERS_PK" ON "NEWS1.0"."USER_PASSWORDS" 
             ("ID") 
            PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
            STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
            PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)
            TABLESPACE "USERS" ;
          --------------------------------------------------------
          --  Constraints for Table USER_PASSWORDS
          --------------------------------------------------------

            ALTER TABLE "NEWS1.0"."USER_PASSWORDS" MODIFY ("ID" NOT NULL ENABLE);

            ALTER TABLE "NEWS1.0"."USER_PASSWORDS" MODIFY ("USER_ID" NOT NULL ENABLE);

            ALTER TABLE "NEWS1.0"."USER_PASSWORDS" MODIFY ("PASSWORD" NOT NULL ENABLE);

            ALTER TABLE "NEWS1.0"."USER_PASSWORDS" ADD CONSTRAINT "USERS_PK" PRIMARY       
            KEY ("ID")
            USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
            STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
            PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)
            TABLESPACE "USERS"  ENABLE;

          --------------------------------------------------------
          --  DDL for Trigger BI_USER_PASSWORDS_ID
          --------------------------------------------------------

            CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "NEWS1.0"."BI_USER_PASSWORDS_ID" 
             before insert on "USER_PASSWORDS" 
             for each row 
          begin  
             if inserting then 
                if :NEW."ID" is null then 
                   select USER_PASSWORDS_SEQ.nextval into :NEW."ID" from dual; 
                end if; 
             end if; 
          end;
          /
          ALTER TRIGGER "NEWS1.0"."BI_USER_PASSWORDS_ID" ENABLE;





          --------------------------------------------------------
          --  DDL for Table USERS
          --------------------------------------------------------

            CREATE TABLE "NEWS1.0"."USERS" 
             (  "ID" NUMBER(*,0), 
            "USERNAME" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
            "PASSWORD" VARCHAR2(255 BYTE), 
            "SALT" BLOB, 
            "EMAIL" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
            "FIRST_NAME" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
            "LAST_NAME" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
            "EMAIL_VERIFIED" NUMBER(*,0) DEFAULT 1, 
            "ACTIVE" NUMBER(*,0) DEFAULT 1, 
            "IP_ADDRESS" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE), 
            "USER_GROUP_ID" NUMBER(*,0), 
            "LAST_PASSWORD_CHANGE_DATE" DATE, 
            "FAILED_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS" NUMBER(*,0), 
            "CREATED" DATE, 
            "CREATEDBY" VARCHAR2(255 BYTE), 
            "MODIFIED" DATE, 
            "MODIFIEDBY" VARCHAR2(255 BYTE)
             ) PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
            STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
            PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)
            TABLESPACE "USERS" 
           LOB ("SALT") STORE AS (
            TABLESPACE "USERS" ENABLE STORAGE IN ROW CHUNK 8192 PCTVERSION 10
            NOCACHE LOGGING 
            STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
            PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)) ;
          --------------------------------------------------------
          --  DDL for Index USERS_UK2
          --------------------------------------------------------

            CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "NEWS1.0"."USERS_UK2" ON "NEWS1.0"."USERS" ("EMAIL") 
            PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
            STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
            PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)
            TABLESPACE "USERS" ;
          --------------------------------------------------------
          --  DDL for Index USERS_UK1
          --------------------------------------------------------

            CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "NEWS1.0"."USERS_UK1" ON "NEWS1.0"."USERS" ("USERNAME") 
            PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
            STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
            PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)
            TABLESPACE "USERS" ;
          --------------------------------------------------------
          --  Constraints for Table USERS
          --------------------------------------------------------

            ALTER TABLE "NEWS1.0"."USERS" MODIFY ("ID" NOT NULL ENABLE);

            ALTER TABLE "NEWS1.0"."USERS" MODIFY ("USERNAME" NOT NULL ENABLE);

            ALTER TABLE "NEWS1.0"."USERS" MODIFY ("PASSWORD" NOT NULL ENABLE);

            ALTER TABLE "NEWS1.0"."USERS" ADD CONSTRAINT "USERS_UK1" UNIQUE 
           ("USERNAME")
            USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
            STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
            PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)
            TABLESPACE "USERS"  ENABLE;

            ALTER TABLE "NEWS1.0"."USERS" ADD CONSTRAINT "USERS_UK2" UNIQUE ("EMAIL")
            USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
            STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
            PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)
            TABLESPACE "USERS"  ENABLE;
```

Comment: Try removing your double quotes from you column names. That should help reduce some of your error messages. Also, before you test the procedure try executing the insert statement as a standalone SQL script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in this section of code:

```
       P_failed_login_attempts     IN NUMBER )
    AS

   BEGIN  

  declare
         user_id_tmp number(20);     

INSERT INTO users( "username" ,
   -- rest omitted
```

Remove the `declare` and move the declaration of `user_id` between the `AS` and the `BEGIN`:

```
       P_failed_login_attempts     IN NUMBER )
    AS
         user_id_tmp number(20);     

   BEGIN  

INSERT INTO users( "username" ,
   -- rest omitted
```

---

In Oracle PL/SQL, a *block* has the form

```
DECLARE
  -- some variable declarations
BEGIN
  -- some code
EXCEPTION
  -- some exception-handling
END;
```

The variable declarations and exception-handling sections are optional.  If there are no variable declarations, you can remove the keyword `DECLARE` (it's not an error if you leave it there).  However, if the block has no exception handling, the `EXCEPTION` keyword must be removed.

When declaring a procedure or function, the `CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ... AS` part takes the place of a `DECLARE`.

The `-- some code` section of a PL/SQL block can contain further blocks inside it.  In fact, this is what the PL/SQL compiler thought you wanted when it saw your `declare` keyword.  It thought you were doing something like the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE USP_USER_ADD (
  -- parameters omitted
)
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE
    -- some variable declarations
  BEGIN
    -- some code
  END;
END USP_USER_ADD;
```

However, you had an `INSERT` after the `declare`. The compiler wasn't expecting that, and that's why you got an error.  You also got an error about end-of-file, and that was because the PL/SQL compiler was expecting two `END`s but got to the end of your stored procedure before it found the second one.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should remove `DECLARE`.

[Oracle 11g Create Procedure Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/create_procedure.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Previous answers have cleared up the compile errors, so I won't address those. But you have a potential bug in place; the id inserted into "user_password" table may not be the same as in "user" table In a multi-user environment it is possible another user could insert and commit into after you insert into set but before you do the select max. That would hopefully raise dup-val-on-index, but would be extremely difficult to find.

You can remove this possibility, and have slightly less/cleaner(?) code by getting the id assigned  by a trigger?) by using the return option on the insert itself:

insert into user ( ... ) values (...) returning id into user_id_tmp ;

and delete the select max(id) ... statement.